# Custom Scroll Bar Control on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-8

I wanna build scroll bar like this

[image: scroll bar looks]

It almost the same like Toggle Switch but it has 3 states. False, not doing anything, and true. And I want my scroll bar is animated whenever the user release the finger from the scrollbar. I am using manipulation completed event to detect it. So when the book image near text "sudah" the book image will move slowly to the right until reach the edge. And that animation also works for 2 different states. Which will move to center or move to left until reach the edge. I am already trying using slider class and also make own control which using storyboard but nothing works. This is the attached of my control.

[Scrollbar Custom Control](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bt5vmakfyqurfbw/ScrollBarCustomControl.zip)

[Slider Custom Control](https://www.dropbox.com/s/smktkgycswznrjo/SliderCustomControl.zip)

[assets](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cjwg7qkz3j3lemy/Assets.zip)

Comment: Does the WP8 SL ToggleButton not support [IsThreeState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.togglebutton.isthreestate.aspx) property? I mean you could make what you're asking with just a custom style template it seems like if it does.

Comment: @ChrisW. WP Toolkit `ToggleSwitch` doesn't have "IsThreeState", but it looks like it does support an "Indeterminate" state by default ...

Comment: @McGarnagle ah well thats a shame, sounds like possibly still do-able though, I need to make an excuse to mess with WP more, might use this as an excuse later to get the OP sorted. Cheers